# The confidence interval is $[2.663; 2.937]$?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

The concentration of calcium in the blood for a given population follows a normal law of mean μ = 2.8 mmol / L and standard deviation σ = 0.7 mmol / L. If we take a sample of 100 people, what is the confidence interval of the calcium concentration at the 95% confidence level.

I got the confidence interval [2.663; 2.937] but I think this is wrong.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, you could try https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Next time you ask, write down *how* you got the answer and *why* you think it may be wrong. Both of those things are often more helpful than the answer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know the population standard deviation $\sigma = 0.7$ so we can find $z^*$ by:
$$
z^* =  \Phi^{-1}(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})
$$
As we want a 95% confidence level we have $\alpha = 0.05$, this means $z^* = 1.96$. We also know the population mean $\mu = 2.8$ so we can get the confidence interval by plugging in the values (including $n=100$):
$$
\left(\mu - z^* \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}, \mu + z^* \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \right) = (2.6628, 2.9372)
$$

I hope it helps :)